# Low speed of qtablewidget.resizeRowsToContents

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5

I add my sqlite.db data to qtablewidget.With the below code :

```
 with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        conn.text_factory = str
        cur.execute(" SELECT text FROM Table WHERE priority = ?", (m,))
        self.SuraBRS.setRowCount(self.Acount)
        all_rows = cur.fetchall()
        a = 0
        for row in all_rows:
           Scontent = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("{}".format(row[0]))
           self.SuraBRS.setItem(a, 0, Scontent )
           self.SuraBRS.resizeRowsToContents()
           a = a + 1
        return
```

But the problem here is the low speed of resizerowstocontents when the rows are more than 60.My data is text.FYI I used pandas it didn't make any change.The problem is just with the widget and I may use qtableview instead.Any idea how to use qtableview for this.

Comment: move `self.SuraBRS.resizeRowsToContents()` outside the for loop. 
You only have to call him once, not every time.

Comment: You are an Angel  eyllanesc.Thanks a lot.you solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `self.SuraBRS.resizeRowsToContents()` outside the for loop. You only have to call him once, not every time